# Do while loop . Make exception for the 1st record and continue on the loop as usual

Tags: shell, loops, sed, awk, while-loop

I have do while loop that'll get filenames and run commands. Pretty standard stuff . What I want to do is sort the files that I feed to the Do While loop and then for the 1st file I want to run a command1 and for the rest of them command2

```
find  $dir -iname  "$search*" |<some commands> | sort -nr
while read filename; do
 # if its the very 1st file .  head - 1 would do that 

echo "command1 > log > 2>&1& " >> appendfile 
echo "if [ $? != 0 ] then ; exit 1 fi " >> appendfile

# for all other files do this 
echo "command1 > log > 2>&1& " >> appendfile
```

Now you see what I am doing too. I am writing stuff to appendfile.ksh which will be run later on. I am choosing the 1st file that is smallest in size as "test file"  to run command1. If the job abends that exit else continue on processing the rest of the files
I am trying a way how to accommodate the 1st file that enters the Do While with a slightly special treatment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a compound command to consume the first file name separately, before the `while` loop starts. This has the benefit of allowing you to append all output of the compound command to `appendfile` with a single redirection, without needing to redirect each `echo` command separately. Be sure to note the corrected redirection syntax for each command as well.

```
find  $dir -iname  "$search*" |<some commands> | sort -nr | {
    # This read gets the first line from the pipeline
    read filename
    echo "command1 > log 2>&1 "
    echo "if [ $? != 0 ] then ; exit 1 fi "

    # These reads will get the remaining lines
    while read filename; do
        echo "command2 > log2 2>&1 "
        echo "if [ $? != 0 ] then ; exit 1 fi "
    done
}  >> appendfile   # If appendfile isn't written to before, you can just use >
```

And one more bit of unsolicited advice: you can shorten your script by doing

```
command1 > log 2>&1 || exit 1
```

instead of using an explicit `if` statement.

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash
f=1
find . -name "*.txt" | while IFS= read -r filename
do
   if [ $f -eq 1 ]; then
      echo First file
   else
      echo Subsequent file
   fi
   ((f++))
done
```

Comment: +1 but `while read filename` should be `while IFS= read -r filename` unless the OP specifically wants to strip spaces off file names and interpret backslshes.

Comment: Thank you, Ed. I am aware of that, but was focussing on the principle of "f=1; if [..]; ((f++))" rather than correcting/critiquing the OP's looping technique. I'll update my answer so the "poor example" disappears. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
first=""

while read filename; do
  if [ -z "$first" ]; then
     first="$filename"
     # if its the very 1st file .  head - 1 would do that 
     echo "command1 > log > 2>&1& " >> appendfile 
     echo "if [ $? != 0 ] then ; exit 1 fi " >> appendfile
  else
     # for all other files do this 
     echo "command2 > log > 2>&1& " >> appendfile 
  fi
done < <(find "$dir" -iname "$search*" | <some commands> | sort -nr)
```